# why does cold water have Translucent visibility?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water

If ice is to formed soon, why ice Does not have Tranparent vision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it becomes translucent because the air that was dissolved in it comes out of solution to form tiny bubbles within the mass of ice.

To avoid this, ice that is intended for use in drinks is frozen in a way that gets rid of the air bubbles. This makes the resulting ice cubes perfectly transparent, which is what people want in their whiskey.

Comment: Indeed.  https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Clear-Ice